# Can I submit a manuscript with 'submittere'?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, modern-life

As a scientist, I frequently find myself submitting a manuscript to a journal for peer review and hopefully publication.
What would be a good Latin verb for this sense of "submit"?
It could also be a longer phrase akin to "submit for review".

There is the obvious candidate verb *submittere*, which evidently is where the English verb comes from.
But that is no proof that the verb can actually be used to mean what the English verb means.
And even if the intended one was indeed one of the meanings, there could be another one leading to a dangerously different interpretation.

[L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=summitto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) gives several meanings for the verb.
A basic meaning, evident from the constituents, is "to put under", which could be a sensible choice if an implicit noun like "review" is supplied and putting under scrutiny is idiomatic enough in Latin.
It also means "send" or "send secretly", which are not wholly inappropriate either.
It may be a reasonable word, but it certainly does not strike me as a perfect fit.

So, how would you express the submission of a manuscript in Latin and why?
While I see value in classical precedent, I would like something that works in today's use.

Comment: FWIW, in Spanish you use _mandar/enviar_ which roughly correspond to a plain **mittere**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I was looking at Ainsworth (previous question) I followed his proposal:

> *permitto*  submit for approval,

L&S thinks *submitto* and *permitto* are both rather submissively inhibited. Try instead:

> *[Commendo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=commendo&la=la#lexicon)* com-mendo (conm- ), āvi, ātum, 1, v. a. 1. mando,
>   I. **Prop.**
>   A. Lit., implying a physical delivery, to deposit with, intrust to; constr. aliquem or aliquid alicui,

Comment: *Commendo tibi oves quas tradidisti mihi* - yes indeed, because you are indeed handing the manuscript over to someone’s care, to look after it, nourish it, and make itfruxtify into a publication.